# How to recover the . gitconfig file from my home directory?

Tags: git, macos

How can I restore or re-generate a removed `~/.gitconfig` file?

I thought about re-install git but as I understood [it's not a recommended option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/244041) for macos.

- MacOS version - 12.6
- Git version 2.37.0 (Apple Git-136)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.git` folder is created in a repo. Unless you are trying to version control your home directory, a `.git` folder won't be in your home directory.

A user home directory may contain a `.gitconfig` file for configuration options.

If you made your home directory into a repo and have a copy/clone of the repo elsewhere you can restore from that.

The `.git` folder and/or `.gitconfig` file can be restored from Time Machine or another backup solution. They are just folders and files.

If there isn't history of importance you can recreate the repo of your home directory. Likewise if there isn't much config, you can run `git config --global ...` to recreate the config values.

(Also note that macOS doesn't use `/home`. User home directories are in `/Users`.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish your folder to git services such as GitHub before you removed the git folder? If yes, you can clone that folder from GitHub

Comment: My question isn't about `.git` folder in any repository. I asked about the `.git` directory located by this `~/.git` (`/home/user`)path.

Comment: A `.git` folder is always part of a repository. If you had that in your user folder, that means you had a repository in your user folder. This answer still applies.

Comment: I'm talking about `.git` directory containing the git configuration data like username, email, auth and etc. Not about repository configuration data, I didn't create a repo by `/home`.

Comment: You mean the `.gitconfig` file.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanDodds. Yes, I'm talking about it.